# Differnce between train_test_split and StratifiedShuffleSplit

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, train-test-split

I came across the following statement when trying to find the differnce between `train_test_split` and `StratifiedShuffleSplit`.

> When `stratify` is not None train_test_split uses `StratifiedShuffleSplit` internally,

I was just wondering why the `StratifiedShuffleSplit` from `sklearn.model_selection` is used when we can use the `stratify` argument available in `train_test_split`.

Comment: When quoting, please always include a link to the source; such a statement cannot be found in the current version of the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mainly, it is done for the sake of the re-usability. Rather than duplicating the code already implemented for `StratifiedShuffleSplit`, `train_test_split` just calls that class.
For the same reason, when `stratify=False`, it uses the `model_selection.ShuffleSplit` class (see [source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/c854b83c91dd8c1bf9282112dba10d50e43b59a4/sklearn/model_selection/_split.py#L2376)).

Please note that duplicating code is considered a bad practice, because it assumed to inflate maintenance costs, but also considered defect-prone as inconsistent changes to code duplicates can lead to unexpected behavior. Here a [reference](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=5070547&casa_token=zH1L8Z0I5BcAAAAA:MHoHhPcCWgYUtncZeBZ_6Z4vATcdOcnegifHyks8UkVNxJ9GR0rCLiOamL8ul0Ij3vViKuwQvw) if you'd like to learn more.

Besides, although they perform the same task, they cannot be always used in the same contexts. For example, `train_test_split` cannot be used within a Random or Grid search with `sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV` or `sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV`.
The `StratifiedShuffleSplit` does. The reason is that the former is not "an iterable yielding (train, test) splits as arrays of indices". While the latter has a method `split` that **yields** (train, test) splits as array of indices.
More info [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV.html) (see parameter **cv**).

Comment: Thank you so much. This answer helped a lot